# Copy images from Folder and paste it to Excel through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

We have Pictures (Jpeg,Jpg,PNG) in a folder, I need to copy these pictures to excel worksheet like A2, B2, C2, D2 cells.

Using below code i am able to copy as A2,A3,A4 and so on but how to change colunm in below code instead of Row. I could make row constant by keeping counter constant.

I have used online tutorial code and changed a bit to match my requirement.

```
Sub AddOlEObject()

    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("SingleProfile").Activate
    Folderpath = "C:\Users\sandeep.hc\Pics"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                 counter = counter + 1
                  'Sheets("Object").Range("A" & counter).Value = fls.Name
                  'Sheets("Object").Range("B" & counter).ColumnWidth = 25
                'Sheets("Object").Range("B" & counter).RowHeight = 100
                Sheets("SingleProfile").Range("A" & counter).Activate
                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter)
                Sheets("SingleProfile").Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next
mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter)
'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            '.Width = 50
            '.Height = 70
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & counter).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & counter).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

**Need help for Optimizing below code**

As per the inputs from users i was able to get the solution which i desired.

I want to optimize the code now, as i am very novice in coding can some one help to optimize or help good coding techniques to improve below

```
Sub AddOlEObject()

    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("SingleProfile").Activate
    Folderpath = "C:\Users\sandeep.hc\Pics"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
       strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
            Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                 counter = 29
                 counter1 = counter1 + 1

                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter, counter1)
                'Sheets("SingleProfile").Activate
                counter1 = counter1 + 17
            End If
        End If
    Next
mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter, counter1)
'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 875
            .Height = 300
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, counter1).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, counter1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ActiveSheet.Range("C2")` use `ActiveSheet.Cells(2,3)` and so on.

By the way, it would be safer to pass the sheet as another function parameter instead of activating it. That way you don't need to remember to activate it every time you call the function. I'd also recommend using `Option Explicit` at the start of your module, especially if you're new to VBA.

Comment: Thanks @arcadeprecinct for your input in mean time while i was trying i found same piece of help from below link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820928.aspx

As am new to VBA, i was trying to solve the problem first, i will consider your points to improve my code.. In few lines if possible give a example of creating a function parameter to activate sheet.. 
thank you so much for your valuable time and help

Comment: `Function insert(PicPath As String, counter As Long, ws As Worksheet) As ` Then `Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter, Sheets("SingleProfile"))` The declaration of the data types helps to prevent type mismatches because it will tell you if you are trying to pass a workbook instead of a worksheet etc. In fact, you don't need a function here because you don't want it to return anything. Use a sub (short for subroutine) instead. (`Option Explicit` would tell you that the data type is missing for that function)

Comment: can you please help to optimize or standardize unwanted line of codes in above updated code part.

Comment: If the code is working and you want to make it nicer there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for that.
Off the top of my head I would suggest checking out the `Dir` function (to possibly replace the FileSystemObject) and `Right` to replace `InStr` (so you don't pick files like `thisisnotajpg.txt`). Also rename your counter and counter1 variables so it's clear which is which (row and column). Plus the stuff I already said in my other posts.

Comment: @arcadeorecinct thanks sir, one more important point need to be helped, i have copied the image to excel from local folder by running the vba code, and if i send the excel as mail attachment to other place the image wont be present only blank space will be there in the workbook does my code have a problem in pasting it?

Comment: Loop up `SaveWithDocument` for adding pictures. This is a new question though and the comments of another answer are not the right place for that.

Answer (score 1):

For shifting through row 1 columns

```
   .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 1).Left
   .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(counter,1).Top
```